# Invoque .cpp method inside .h

Tags: c++, visual-c++, onclick

I am trying to program a simple Windows Forms application with Visual C++

My problem is that I have built a function on .cpp

#### Form1.cpp

```
bool function()
{
    //code
}
```

The problem is that I am trying to call this function from the .h file do to a Click on a Button

#### Form1.h

```
private: 
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    bool result = function();
}
```

I am having compiling errors.

I read in a previous thread to "Try declaring the body of your `onClick` in the .cpp file."
The thing is... I am not sure what exactly should I put in the .cpp file?

Thank you for your time; any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put a prototype of the function before its use.

```
bool function();
void whatever::button_click()
{
    bool result = function();
}
```

You can even put the prototype into the function if you don't want it to be visible outside of it:

```
void whatever::button_click()
{
    bool function();
    bool result = function();
}
```

Of course, if the function in the .cpp file does not match the prototype you will get a **linker** error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you don't understand why everything is as it is in the c++ world.
Let's say you want to make a class Foo that has a function Bar, it's very easy you just do

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar(){/*code*/}
};
```

And now you have the Foo class in a file, but you also need a Baz class that has to be in another file. You can't move Foo, so C++ has the #include system. This way you can have Foo in a file, Baz in another and still get to use them both. A theoretical example could be:

```
#include "Foo.h"
class Baz
{
     Foo* foo;
};
```

Which to the compiler translates as such (consider for now that Foo.h contains what I wrote earlier):

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar(){/*code*/}
}; 

class Baz
{
     Foo* foo;
};
```

But this is very inefficient for a number of reasons, first of all if we kept everything like this the compiler would have to compile the same thing every time you #included a file somewhere else, so C++ has another mechanism that allows you to tell the compiler that class Foo exists somewhere else and it will be available in the future and it looks somewhat like this, so when you make a class in C++ you use the .h file to describe how it should look like and keep the implementation in the cpp file. In this case it would look like this:

```
//Foo.h

class Foo
{
    void Bar();
}; 

//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::Bar(){/*code*/}

//Baz
#include "Foo.h"
class Foo
{
    void Bar(){/*code*/}
};
```

So TLDR, what you need to do is remove the function definition leaving it as

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
```

And in the cpp file have

```
System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    bool result = function();
}
```